# Convert HTML string to JSON array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following string:

```
let disposibleHTML = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";
```

I would like it to be as such:

```json
{
    "cid1": "2",
    "cid2": "3",
    "seqno": "4",
    // and so on
}
```

Here is my current approach:

```
let n = disposibleHTML.replace('<html>', '');
let splitedArray = n.split("&amp;");
let json = { ...splitedArray }
console.log(json);
```

Which produces the output below:

```json
{0: 'cid1=1122', 1: 'cid2=2', 2: 'seqno=3', 3: 'tdate=20220616', 4: 'ttime=11355525', 5: 'cname=Test ECSI', 6: 'payment_method=', 7: 'payon=4', 8: 'amount=5', 9: 'productcode=ff', 10: 'PaymentStatus=Approved</html>'}
```

How can I fix this issue and get the desired output?

Comment: Protip: using `replace` and `split` to parse a string is a strong indication that you're doing something incorrectly. A regex would be better - how familiar are you with thigs like the Chomsky hierarchy?

Comment: Ahhhhh! never heard about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use reduce for that:

```js
let disposibleHTML = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";
let n = disposibleHTML.replace('<html>', '').replace('</html>', '');
let splitedArray = n.split("&amp;");
let json = splitedArray.reduce((p, c) => {let t = c.split('='); p[t[0]] = t[1]; return p;}, {});
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Good idea using reduce to construct an object.

Answer (score 3):

You can clean up the string and use URLSearchParams to get the values.

```js
const disposibleHTML = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";

const result = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(disposibleHTML.replace(/<\/?html>/g, '').replace(/&amp;/g,'&')));

// everything as strings
console.log(result);
```

If you want them as numbers you can add some more processing.

```js
const disposibleHTML = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";

const result = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(disposibleHTML.replace(/<\/?html>/g, '').replace(/&amp;/g,'&')));

Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(isFinite(value)) result[key] = +value;
});


// everything as strings
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sightly ugly but should suffice:

```js
const str = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";

const obj = JSON.parse("{" + str.replace('<html>', '').replace('</html>', '').replaceAll('amp;', '').split('&').map(e => e.split('=').map(f => `"${f}"`).join(':')).join(',') + "}");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

I went about it in a different way than others .. Just because:

```js
let disposibleHTML = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";

let n = disposibleHTML.replace('<html>', '');
n = n.replace('</html>', '');
let splitedArray = n.split("&amp;");

const mainArr = [];
let count = 0;

for (const item of splitedArray) {
    item.replace('"', '');
  items = item.split('=');
  mainArr[count] = items;
  count++;
}

let finalJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainArr));

console.log(finalJSON);
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar idea but perhaps slightly more understandable. Basically we split the string on `&amp`, thus constructing an array like `["cid1=2", "cid2=3", ...]`. Then we loop over each item in the array using `Array.reduce`, split the the item on the `=` sign, and append that to an object.

```js
let disposibleHTML = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";

let n = disposibleHTML.replace('<html>', '').replace('</html>', '');
let splitedArray = n.split("&amp;");

let keyMap = [...splitedArray];
const json = keyMap.reduce((values, item) => {
  const [key, value] = item.split("=");
  return {
    ...values,
    [key]: value
  }
}, {})

console.log(json)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `String.prototype.replace` and `.split` and other *surprisingly nontrivial* string operations is not the best way to process string input (in fact, if you ever catch yourself using `split` it means you're probably doing something wrong, even for CSV (i.e. `split(',')`) because a CSV value can contain a comma when enclosed in quotes).

Also, you're processing what looks like HTML-encoded `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-data contained within a dummy `<html>` element.

I think the *best approach* would be to use JavaScript+DOM's built-in HTML decoding abilities, then use `URLSearchParams` to *correctly* parse the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data out, then build a JS `object` by enumerating over name/value pairs, like so:

```js
let disposibleHTML = "<html>cid1=2&amp;cid2=3&amp;seqno=4&amp;tdate=20220616&amp;ttime=11355525&amp;cname=Test E&amp;payment_method=&amp;payon=33&amp;amount=5&amp;productcode=gp&amp;PaymentStatus=Approved</html>";

function run() {

    const urlEncodedParams = htmlDecode( disposibleHTML );
    const obj = urlParamsToJSObject( urlEncodedParams );
    
    console.log( "urlencoding to JS object: %o", obj );
}

run();

function htmlDecode( html ) {

    const el = document.createElement('div')
    el.innerHTML = disposibleHTML;
    return el.textContent;
}

function urlParamsToJSObject( p ) {

    let parsed;
    try {
        parsed = new URLSearchParams( p );
    }
    catch( err ) {
        console.error( err );
        throw new Error( "Couldn't parse URL-encoded text: " + err );// err; // TODO: Better handling?
    }
    
    //
    
    const obj = {};
    for( const key of parsed.keys() ) {
        const firstValue = parsed.get( key );
        obj[ key ] = firstValue;
    }
    
    return obj;
}
```